# How to print multiple same tag with different output/class using beautiful soup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, tags

This is my first time using BeautifulSoup.

I have this `test.html`

```
<html>
<body>
<div class='ts'>2012-03-14 09:17:55.433 +0300&nbsp;</div><div class='log'>No Error</div>
<div class='ts'>2012-03-14 12:18:55.433 +0300&nbsp;</div><div class='log'>Error: Missing module.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to find all line that have `div` tag and class `ts` with `log` and print the result like this on the terminal

```
<div class='ts'>2012-03-14 09:17:55.433 +0300&nbsp;</div><div class='log'>No Error</div>
<div class='ts'>2012-03-14 12:18:55.433 +0300&nbsp;</div><div class='log'>Error: Missing module.</div>
```

My code so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"))

def find_ts_and_log():
    items = soup.select('div.ts') + soup.select('div.log')
    for item in items:
        print item

find_ts_and_log()
```

But this script gave me this result

```
<div class='ts'>2012-03-14 09:17:55.433 +0300&nbsp;</div>
<div class='ts'>2012-03-14 12:18:55.433 +0300&nbsp;</div>
<div class='log'>No Error</div>
<div class='log'>Error: Missing module.</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_all()` with `class_` filter :

```
items = soup.find_all('div', class_=['ts','log'])
for item in items:
    print item
```

Or you can find `div.ts` first and then get corresponding `log` from `next_sibling` property :

```
items = soup.select('div.ts')
for item in items:
    print item, item.next_sibling
```

Comment: To OP: In your actual code, you might need to check whether `item` has `next_sibling` and if it has, then check the sibling tag name and class attribute value (check if the sibling satisfy selector `div.log`) ...

Comment: thank you for your help. your 2nd suggestion works for me.